# how to use IF to test if a value meets a certain mask

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I have a variable and I need to test if it contain a formated value like this
........-....-....-....-............

the variable can contem any value in any format, and I need to test if the value is like 1572C097-4452-4495-8369-C7606F2C867E

I tried using `sed` to retrieve the value from another variable

```
tguid=$(echo $i |sed 's/.*\(........-....-....-....-............\).*/\1/')
```

But now, I dont have a clue
how can I use if [] statement to guarantee if the variable tguid have the correct value?

Comment: Are those all sedecimal digits? And what exactly do you mean *the correct value*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `sed`. A conditional expression can test whether a string matches a regexp directly.

```
if [[ $i =~ .{8}-.{4}-.{4}-.{4}-.{12} ]]
then
    echo It matches
else
    echo It does not match
fi
```

Comment: Or maybe `[[:xdigit:]]` instead of `.`.

Comment: Maybe. The example looks like hex, but nothing in the question stipulates it. And the pattern is so unlikely with incorrect digits that it's probably not worth the trouble to be explicit.